# truncate a specific string in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in a view and I want to truncate it at 17 characters, but my syntax is off. What would be the correct one?

Currently getting the following error:

```
NameError in UsersController#show
```

Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6"> <h3>Portfolio</h3><h2>  
<%= link_to @user.portfolio_title, "#{@user.portfolio}" , 
truncate(h2.html_safe, :length => 17), :target => "_blank"  %> </h2> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `h2` as a variable in the first parameter of `truncate`, I'm guessing you want `@user.portfolio.html_safe` or similar?

Edit: It should probably be `link_to truncate(@user.portfolio_title.html_safe, :length => 17), "#{@user.portfolio}", :target => "_blank"`

Comment: correct! but when I do that I get this error `ArgumentError in UsersController#show
wrong number of arguments (4 for 0..3)`

Comment: ok i just realized one thing. the only issue now is that it is appending the link to the host link. i.e., dell.com/users/Apple.com (if the link is apple.com), when it should just open apple.com. any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any of `*_path` methods? Can you post the HTML that it generates and the value of the string you pass as the second parameter to link_to?

Comment: ok so i fixed this. but on heroku it gave an error because of .html_safe.